# Show a view when keyboard hides and vice versa

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard

Below is what my app looks like. Its a messaging app.

[image]

There are two fragments in one screen Fragment1 (Beige color) and Fragment2 (Dark grey color). The EditText and "+" button are inside Fragment2. Initially Fragment1, EditText and + button are visible.

1. When I click on EditText, keyboard comes up, obviously and the EditText and + button comes above keyboard.
2. when I click on + button then Layout2 of Fragment2 is visible and the keyboard hides if visible.
3. If I click on EditText and Layout2 is visible then Layout2 hides and keyboard comes up.

Now my problem is that the switching from Keyboard to Layout2 and vice versa is not smooth. The screen kinda flickers. What I want is:

1. If keyboard is visible and I click + button, then the EditText and + button should stay there, keyboard should go down and Layout2 should come up.
2. If layout2 is visible and I click on EditText, then there are two possibilities.

   A. Either EditText and + button should stay there, Layout2 should go down and keyboard should come up smoothly.

   B. Or EditText, + button should stay there, keyboard should come up and Layout should go down after.

My user experience is kinda bad with all these jerks and flickers. Please help me out in implementing this smooth transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with a :

```
Layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


EditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(booleanIsClicked){
                  Layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

or

```
EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(.....

 Layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

.)
```